# Mongoose: find() возвращает пустой массив

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

метод find() возвращает пустой массив. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Схема:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

get:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запись в базе есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в get вывожу orders в консоль, и мне выводит пустой массив:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вы уверены, что у вас правильный user id приходит?

Comment: да, на фото их можно сравнить (в коносоли после массива и в базе)

Comment: Уберите .populate() и посмотрите, возвращает ли вам find что-то, для начала.